# Display wordpress comments before the plugins?

Tags: comments, wordpress, editing

I want to display the wp comments right after the post, but before the plugins content.

What I have tried so far:

in single-products.php file, the original code is:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages','eStore').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
<?php edit_post_link(__('Edit this page','eStore')); ?>
```

I tried put the comments(comments_template()) before and after the "the_content()", but its not correct. If I put:

- Before the_content(), it displays the comments section before the real content
- After the_content(), the comments are displayed below others plugin (simple social and Five rate stars plugins)

Is there anyway to insert in between them, I mean, between the post and plugins?

FYI: The theme that I am using, didnt display comment, so I have to display/enable it by myself. I am using wp 3.0.1

Comment: This is an ideal question for the WordPress Stack Exchange http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: WOW.. i never knew there is a wordpress version of SO!! thanks so much, I am moving my question to there now =) Thanks lots, bud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how your plugins are adding themselves. If it is via a widget, you can move the widget region in the template between the post and comments. Otherwise, you may have an option to manually call the plugins in the page template instead of them automatically adding themselves in, if that is in fact what they are doing. Check the readme.txt files that came with the plugins, most plugins offer the ability to be manually called in the template.